# Python 3x: IndexError - tuple out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble with this project, which is functional immediately after coding, but then breaks as such in PyCharm:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 38, in <module>
1

    exec("dict" + str(x) + "['Team'] = '" + Sponsors[randint(1, len(Sponsors))] + " " + Cars[randint(1, len(Cars))] + "'")
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

How can I fix this error?
Also, if it is a train-wreck, please tell me: I am a relative newcomer to Python, and may be going about things the long-winded way.

```
#RallyCarsProject

from random import randint
from random import shuffle
import time

#Tuples to create names
Cars = "Honda", "Subaru", "Vauxhall", "Peugeot", "Renault", "Mitsubishi", "Audi", "Mini", "BMW", "Fiat", "Nissan", "Ford", "Kia", "Hyundai", "Suzuki", "Volvo", "Toyota", "Citroen", "Mercedes", "Jaguar", "Mazda", "Infiniti", "Saturn", "Chevrolet", "Cadillac", "Pontiac", "Tesla", "Volkswagen", "Skoda"
Sponsors = "Halfords", "QuikFit", "Castrol", "Shell", "BP", "WD40", "GO Outdoors", "Dunlop", "Michelin", "Mobil 1", "Brembo", "Sparco", "Marlboro", "Esso", "Texaco", "Pirelli", "Gulf", "Blitz", "Motul", "K&N"
Fnames = "Kimberlee", "Jack", "Doyle", "Scotty", "Nichelle", "Kitty", "Fredia", "Van", "Erminia", "Cornell", "Chas", "Bennett", "Crystal", "Donny", "Florene", "Francesca", "Prince", "Johnsie", "Stepanie", "Adolfo", "Gilda", "Ike", "Lanelle", "Monserrate", "Erasmo", "Darci", "Refugia", "Clarine", "Alesia", "Luciano", "Genaro", "Valentin", "Howard", "Whitney", "Lou", "Roy", "Willis", "Dewayne", "Giuseppe", "Terence", "Rene", "Noe", "Gregory", "Al", "Earnest", "Lacy", "Michale", "Calvin", "Leandro", "Chung", "Lowell", "Keven", "Olen", "Tim", "Edmond", "Edmond", "Paul", "Truman", "Dario", "Mel", "Rickie", "Victor", "Rubin", "Shannon", "Zane", "Reid", "George", "Diego", "Denver", "Broderick", "Dwain", "Benny", "Chase", "Abram", "Terrell", "Wally", "Stephen", "Phil", "Lynn", "Major", "Marlin", "Tomas", "Zack", "Quentin", "Claudio", "Tad", "Virgilio", "Cornelius", "Karl", "Ian", "Carlos", "Clemente", "Theron", "Filiberto", "Galen", "Winfred", "Gilberto", "Porfirio", "Neal", "Doug", "Demarcus", "Shon", "Geoffrey", "Houston", "Isreal", "Rudolf", "Cecil", "Hipolito", "Martin", "Antwan", "Riley", "Domenic", "Bennie", "Chester", "Shannon", "Isaac", "Roman", "Billie", "Hyman", "Bradford", "Vernon", "Tyson", "Gordon", "Trevor", "Rhett", "Hobert", "Leif", "Alexander", "Maximo", "Adalberto", "Gary", "Rafael", "Freddy", "Joel", "Kieth", "Tad", "Mitchell", "Margarito", "Paul", "Palmer", "Mauro", "Sanford", "Darryl", "Alejandro", "Weldon", "Ahmed", "Federico"
Lnames = "Parkinson", "Russel", "Jenney", "Sapers", "Zalkalns", "Lally", "Zucker", "Quelch", "Devita", "Mora", "Defoe", "Garnett", "Rosado", "Heanue", "Ninon", "Galton", "Carlson", "Young", "Checa", "Mcneal", "Sjostrom", "Broderick", "Gabriels", "Koniaris", "Vines", "Shang", "Mishra", "Simons", "Mulford", "Rousseau", "Johnsen", "Cimbalo", "Sheridan", "Teisberg", "Grynkiewicz", "O'Neill", "Silver", "Glasman", "Goldizen", "Cupal", "Bernassola", "Corsini", "Soccorsi", "Barese", "Ouyang", "Schnur", "Cazden", "Wirka", "Cuccurullo", "Scanlon", "Lacount", "Lauterbach", "Wayland", "Devivo", "Price", "Tiffany", "Prestwich", "Orchard", "Elmore", "Plato", "Drew", "Davidian", "Vitali", "Aureli", "Seed", "Fujimoto", "Carlyle", "Leder", "Hallmann", "Bruzik", "Mchale", "Maruca", "Southey", "Crane", "Soon", "Strachan", "Velupillai", "Frommer", "Antonov", "Fortunato", "Vittadini", "Cushman", "Glasser", "Gelberman", "Leavitt", "Gwinn", "Knight", "Holyoke", "Davidsen", "Dynkin", "Giudici", "Alspach", "Kornai", "Ahumada", "Engelhardt", "Halliday", "Posner", "Self", "Schaefer", "Edelman", "Ramian", "Madore", "Royal", "Fearnley", "Heidbreder", "Bronson", "Kisiel", "Horgan", "Boatman", "Woolf", "Shea", "O'Connor", "Chipman", "Kotilainen", "Hanlon", "Hayden-Smith", "Bachelder", "Linehan", "Athanassakis", "Nagaran", "Pearce", "Gallucio", "Siner", "Jardetzky", "Blanchette", "Chiozzi", "Turrall", "Rothbard", "Mortera", "Joensen", "Tocqueville", "Ibarra", "Shlyakhter", "Strugnell", "Wolff", "Sheerr", "Tso", "Hogan", "Matsumura", "Keats", "Shechter", "Kokkinis", "Levenson", "Fiori", "Holleran", "Satoh", "Warfield", "Coleman", "Geisser", "Zaidi", "Holtzclaw", "Zapatka", "Stimpfle", "de Sena"
Stages = "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Antigua & Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Central African Rep", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo", "Congo (Democratic Republic of)", "Costa Rica", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Greece", "Grenada", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland (Republic of)", "Israel", "Italy", "Ivory Coast", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea North", "Korea South", "Kosovo", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macedonia", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mexico", "Micronesia", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar (Burma)", "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Qatar", "Romania", "Russian Federation", "Rwanda", "St Kitts & Nevis", "St Lucia", "Saint Vincent & the Grenadines", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Sao Tome & Principe", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Sudan", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Togo", "Tonga", "Trinidad & Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Tuvalu", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Vatican City", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"

#Intro and sleep for reading time
print("Welcome to the World Rally Championship!")
time.sleep(1)

#Create number of teams and races
teams = randint(10,16)
races = randint(5,12)
print("This year's competition features", str(teams), "teams competing over", str(races), "races.")

#Creates array, then appends the number of races' worth of array, inside which a tuple length number of competitors
#Shuffles list of competitors to determine positions
results = []
for x in range(1, (races + 1)):
    exec("Stage" + str(x) + "= []")
    for y in range(1, (teams + 1)):
        exec("Stage" + str(x) + ".append(" + str(y) + ")")
    exec("shuffle(Stage" + str(x) + ")")
    exec("results.append(Stage" + str(x) + ".copy())")

#Creates team names, driver and co-driver in storage array
names = []
for x in range(1, (teams + 1)):
    print(str(x))
    exec("dict" + str(x) + "= {}")
    exec("dict" + str(x) + "['Team'] = '" + Sponsors[randint(1, len(Sponsors))] + " " + Cars[randint(1, len(Cars))] + "'")
    exec("dict" + str(x) + "['Driver'] = '" + Fnames[randint(1, len(Sponsors))] + " " + Lnames[randint(1, len(Cars))] + "'")
    exec("dict" + str(x) + "['CoDriver'] = '" + Fnames[randint(1, len(Sponsors))] + " " + Lnames[randint(1, len(Cars))] + "'")
    exec("names.append(dict" + str(x) + ")")
    #Creates variables with iterated names
    exec("Team" + str(x + 1) + "= 0")

#Set scoring system
scores = [25, 18, 15, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1]

#Show teams
for x in range(1, (teams + 1)):
    print("")
    print("Team", str(x) + ":", names[x-1]['Team'])
    print("Driver:", names[x-1]['Driver'])
    print("Co-Driver:", names[x-1]['CoDriver'])
```

Comment: Never use `exec()` or `eval()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating an index between 1 and the length of the tuple *inclusive*:

```
Sponsors[randint(1, len(Sponsors))]
```

Python indexes start at 0, not 1, and the *last permissible index* is the length *minus 1*, so exclusive, not inclusive. This is what causes your `IndexError`:

```
>>> Sponsors = "Halfords", "QuikFit", "Castrol", "Shell", "BP", "WD40", "GO Outdoors", "Dunlop", "Michelin", "Mobil 1", "Brembo", "Sparco", "Marlboro", "Esso", "Texaco", "Pirelli", "Gulf", "Blitz", "Motul", "K&N"
>>> Sponsors[len(Sponsors)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
>>> Sponsors[len(Sponsors) - 1]
'K&N'
```

You'd have to use `Sponsors[random.randrange(len(Sponsors))]` instead, or much better, use `random.choice(Sponsors)`:

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> choice(Sponsors)
'WD40'
>>> choice(Sponsors)
'Blitz'
```

which takes care of the boundaries for you.

Next, there is *no need* to use `exec()` or `eval()` in your code. Create a *top level list* to hold your teams:

```
teams = []
```

and add your dictionaries to that. That way you can just address `teams[0]` for the first team, etc., rather than generate names like `dict1` and `dict2`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback: it's really useful ;)

Comment: Just realised, since I am refreshing stage and dict each time, I can remove the iteration. Silly me.